# Render issues with maxscript

Tags: 3dsmax, maxscript

I'm programming an application and its in need of a plugin in 3dsmax to scan a file in a loop and then render a .max file animation.
So, I have two issues:
1- I can't scan a file in a while loop without getting in trouble with “unresponding error”
2- I can't find any animation render example (Documentation is not really useful!)
I need a working example to render and a solution to scan a file in a loop without an unresponding error. I want to signal my plugin with a .txt file.
I'm in need of an example - opensource or something that can help me.

Note: Can I program my script with python? Is this easier? And which versions support python scripting?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "scan a file"?  If you have problems with your script, why do you not show your script here?  There are examples in the 3ds Max docs about how to initiate a render.  It's very simple.  You can adjust the common render options, file output _etc_ via script.  What do you mean by "I want to signal my plugin with a .txt file"?  Signal it to do what?  This question asks too many questions and gives not enough detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- If you are getting "unresponding error" it is most likely because your script is still executing stuff. Since max is mostly a single threaded application, is it possible that your script contain an infinite loop?

2- There are plenty of example/documentation out there that explain how to render an animation.  All you need to do is to provide the frame to render the method you use to render might influence the way you pass these parameter.  You can also setup most of these directly inside the .max file.

Using the 3dsmaxcmd executable (pay special attention to the frames/start/end options which let you control the frames to be rendered): https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/3ds-max/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2021/ENU/3DSMax-Rendering/files/GUID-E5239450-557C-4F51-8DBE-B9BE22F881CA-htm.html

Using the 3dsMaxBatch executable you can run a script in which you can easily setup the desired rendering parameter and launch the render.
Here is an article on how to use 3dsMaxBatch.exe: https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/3ds-max/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2019/ENU/3DSMax-Batch/files/GUID-48A78515-C24B-4E46-AC5F-884FBCF40D59-htm.html

For more information on how to setup and render using maxscript see this documentation (pay special attention to frame optional parameters which let you control which frame to render): https://help.autodesk.com/view/3DSMAX/2020/ENU/?guid=GUID-9175301C-13E6-488B-ABA6-D27CD804B205

Comment: Thank you so much!and yes i am using a unlimited loop at first of my code because my script is waiting for a signal of another application.